# ngClass condition with url dynamic id

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need a ngClass condition where I add an active class to a list element. I need to have it with both the url '/companies' and '/company/:id'.

The problem is the '/company/:id' does not work. How to make the condition that it works for every id instead of ':id'?

`<li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active': menuActive === '/companies', 'active': menuActive === '/company/:id'}" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">`

Comment: can you give an example for the value in menuActive?

Comment: @Moshezaurus "/company/1" or "/company/r32jas2" any value with combination of strings and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand you are creating an object, so you can't assign the same property twice. If you didn't have any logic to follow there, you could have done something like `<li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{active: menu === 'a' || menu === 'b' }"`

So, you can change the rule in the html to go to the component to check if the class should be active:

```
<li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(menu) }" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
```

and in your component:

```
isActive(menu: string) {
  const menuWithId = /^\/companies\/[a-z0-9]+$/i;
  return menu === "/companies" || menuWithId.test(menu);
}
```